# How to use UITabBar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uipagecontrol

[image]

**Swift language**

**Main issue**

In the image I have a **green** and a **blue** view. I am able to swipe between those two views and now I want to implement a `UITabBar` so I know on which view I selected. I tried `UIPageControl`but I can not customize the indicators in any way. I tried creating a `UITabBarController` but I do not know where to put it.

**First attempt**

If I connect the `UITabBarController` with the **green** and **blue** view using **segues** then the indicator will not load, just the bar.

**Second attempt**

If I connect the `UITabBarController` with the **pageviewcontroller** or the **container** view it will add them into the indicator and when I connect the **blue** and **green** view after I will not be able to slide.

**Last attempt**(not tried it)

The only thing I have not tried is doing it programmatically inside the pageviewcontrollers.swift file. I do not really know how to implement a **TabBar** programmatically and I would like to ask for some help. If you want to know why I would rather have a `UITabBar` instead of **page control** indicator is because I can edit the indicators to icons instead.

**Code in pageviewcontroller**

```
import UIKit

class secondPageViewController: UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        let page4: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page4")
        let page5: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page5")



        pages.append(page4)
        pages.append(page5)



        setViewControllers([page4], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {


        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!


        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)


        if (previousIndex > 0)
        {
            return nil
        }



        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)


        if (nextIndex < 1)
        {
            return nil
        }

        return pages[nextIndex]

    }






    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to answer: https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

Fully functional PageMenu with options.